# Export email as HTML

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, html, export

I want to take backup of my email. The best way I see is to be able to export all the mails as HTML files, one for each mail, and save them to a seperate disk.

However, I don't see any such options or addons for doing this (Thunderbird or Outlook).

Is there a simple way to do this? Any suggestions are welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the [ImportExportTools](https://nic-nac-project.org/~kaosmos/mboximport-en.html) for Thunderbird might be just what you need.

Answer (score 5):

if you are using Outlook 2010 (and i think in the previous version too) you can view the email message in the browser & then from the file -> save as menu save it as html.
to view the email in the browser do the following:

- open the message
- in the 'message' tab on the ribbon click on actions [image: screenshot]
- and then click on 'view in browser'

or follow these keyboard keys (press in that order): **ALT, H, A, V**

you should see the message in the browser (internet explorer) now & now just save it! :)

hope this helps...

Answer (score 3):

[MsgExtract](http://www.maildev.com/msgextract/) can export your email messages from either Outlook or Thunderbird to HTML, however, I would suggest you to save your email messages as PDF for long term storage, because:

- You can read the email message by just clicking on it
- You can embed the attachments and extract them at any time.
- You can include the linked images in the PDF document

MsgExtract can  save the attachments and email meta data embedded in the resulting PDF so that those PDF files can be used as source to export them back to another email client.

(Disclaimer, I am the author of MsgExtract)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do with your backed up mails. Do you want to import mails used in Thunderbird in Outlook or Vice Versa? Do you just want to have the mails backed up in case your Hard drive crashes?

In case you want to have the plain mails I can't test it right now as I don't have access to Thunderbird and Outlook at the moment.

In case you just want data security, all you have to do is back up either your Thunderbird profile (or just the data folder) or your Outlook Data File (pst). The Default locations for both Outlook and Thunderbird Mail should be in AppData.